# Does a differentiable function exist with $f'(0)=0$ but $f'(x_n) \to \infty$ as $x_n \to 0$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, functions, derivatives

Does a differentiable function $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ exist with $f'(0)=0$ where there is a sequence $x_n \to 0$ and $f'(x_n) \to \infty$?

My first thought was to work with the function $f(x) = x^2\sin(1/x)$ if $x \neq 0$ and $f(x) = 0$ if $x = 0$. This function is differentiable with derivative $f'(x) = 2x\sin(1/x) - \cos(1/x)$ if $x \neq 0$ and $f'(0) = 0$ if $x = 0$. My issue now lies with constructing the necessary sequence.

Is my thinking correct so far? Can someone help with constructing the sequence if it is possible, or show me where I went wrong in the case that it isn't possible?

Comment: You only need to modify your first thought a bit. Consider: $$f(x)=|x|^{3/2}\sin(1/x)$$

Comment: I don't think this will work (your $f'$ is clearly bounded on $[-1,1]$). But look at $x^2\sin(1/x^2)$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy I think David meant that the $f'$ in the original post is bounded near $0$, not the other comment

Comment: Can I then use the sequence $x_n = \frac{1}{2\pi n}$?

Comment: The square root of that (for my suggestion)...

Comment: try $x_n=\frac{1}{\sqrt{(2n+1)\pi}}$ it gives $+\infty$  where $f(x)=x^2 \sin(1/x^2)$ for x>0 otherwise 0